# Spark Streaming Context to read CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm having a tough time using StreamingContext to read a CSV and send each row to another method that does other processing. I tried splitting by newline but it splits after three columns (there are about 10 columns per 
row):

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///Users/userName/Documents/Notes/MoreNotes/tmpFolder/")

lines.map{row => {
  val columnValues = row.split("\n")
  (columnValues(0), "\n")
}}.print()
```

If I open the CSV in Excel, there are about 10 values per column. If I open the same file using Sublime or some text editor, there appears to be a newline after those first 3 values. Not sure if it's an encoding thing or just the way Sublime displays it. In any case I'm trying to get the entire row in Spark - not sure if there's a way to do that.

Comment: so "row" is already one line, isn't it? csvs are split by comma or semi colon. Maybe I am missing something? Format of datafile may help in finding an answer

Comment: That's what I thought too. But when I printed 'row', it only prints the first three columns and prints the next three on the next iteration. When I open it in Excel though, all those columns are in the same row

Comment: Maybe to do with the way it is being streamed....i.e., something at the remote socket?

Comment: My experience is that lines are always streamed in whole and handled as a single line by the receiver. What outputstream method are you using on the remote socket?

Comment: @covfefe  why you are using the streaming to read csv file .is there any particular reason for that

Answer (score 1):

`ssc.textFileStream` internally creates a file stream and start splitting on the new line character. But your data is containing the text qualifiers

```
1996, Jeep, "Grand Cherokee, MUST SELL! 
air", moon roof, loaded, 4799.00
```

Here some text is in double quotes and the row is multi lined row. If you try to split the data by `,` it will be:

```
[1996, Jeep, "Grand Cherokee,MUST SELL!]
```

It will miss the other data points because you are splitting by comma. To avoid, that you can use `sqlContext`

```
df = sqlContext.read
               .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
               .option("header", "true")
               .option("inferSchema","true")
               .option("multiLine","true")
               .option("quoteMode","ALL")
               .load(path)
```

Or you can pre-process  your CSV using [Univocity Parser](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) to handle multi-line and double quotes and other special characters, and  put these files in to the directory and start your `ssc.textFileStream` after that.